# Angular js - pushing data from ng-grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ng-grid

I need some help to transfer the data from the ng-grid, to another page.
I'm making an invoice, and when the invoice from the ng-grid is complete, the data must go to another page with another layout, ready to be printed.

I used a service, but something obviously is lacking.
I thought I correctly pushed data into the array.
If i put something in the empty array, in the other page I can see it, so, basically, I just didn't push anything inside from ng-grid. :(

The main Controller, with ng-grid:

> controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){
>
> ```
>   /*empy array, where I would like to push my data*/
>   $scope.dataFatt=[]; 
>   /*array for the ng-grid*/
>   $scope.myData = [{Numero:'1',Descrizione:'a',CostoUnitario:'10',Qta:'1',Totale:''},
>                   {Numero:'2',Descrizione:'b',CostoUnitario:'10',Qta:'1',Totale:''},
>                   {Numero:'',Descrizione:'',CostoUnitario:'',Qta:'',Totale:''},
>                   {Numero:'',Descrizione:'',CostoUnitario:'',Qta:'',Totale:''},
>                   {Numero:'',Descrizione:'',CostoUnitario:'',Qta:'',Totale:''}
>   ];  
>   /*-------------------------GRID-----------------------*/
>  $scope.gridOptions = { 
>     data: 'myData', 
>     selectedItems:$scope.dataFatt,
>     enableCellSelection: true,
>     enableCellEdit: true,
>     enableRowSelection: true,
>     columnDefs: [
>       {cellTemplate: '<button ng-click="addRow()">+</button>',width: 40, enableCellEdit: false},
>       {field: 'Numero', displayName: 'Numero', enableCellEdit: true},
>       {field:'Descrizione', displayName:'Descrizione'},
>       {field: 'CostoUnitario', displayName: 'Costo Unitario', enableCellEdit: true},
>       {field: 'Qta', displayName: 'Qta', enableCellEdit: true},
>       {field: 'getTotale()', displayName: 'Totale', enableCellEdit: false},
>       {cellTemplate: '<input type="button" value="-" ng-click="removeRow($index)"/>',width: 40, enableCellEdit: false }],
>
>   };
> ```

The service that select the items and should push them in to the empty array:

```
controller.factory('DatiFattura', function(){
    return{
        getDati:function(){
            angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(dataFatt, index){
                if (dataFatt.Numero){
                    $scope.gridOption.selectItem(index,true);
                               $scope.data.push(selectItem);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your flow since this isn't the full code, but you could put the variable that holds selectedItems into the service and attach it directly to the grid. Then you can inject the same service into another controller and access the selected items data array to display your printable invoice. [See main.js and service.js in this Plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/e8ZBnKwsh6Y5m6ltm8qn?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you!
Meanwhile my boss asked me to save the data in the database...so... now I have another problem. Hahaha! :D
Thak you for your help.

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but figured you'd ask if you needed it. There are a few Q&A on here for pushing and retrieving data from ng-grid, but if all you need to push is the selected items, it will be fairly straightforward.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628371/ng-submit-and-http-doesnt-send-data-to-the-database?noredirect=1#comment36281134_23628371

heheheheh there is the question...  :(

Comment: If you're new to Angular, I would suggest two things. Get a decent reference book (like "ng-book"), and work through some of the examples. Also, unless you need bleeding edge features (you probably don't), stick with the stable branch versions, the latest of which is 1.2.16 right now.

Comment: I'm doing a stage in a company, and I was in rush, cause they needed the application. :D
But, I'll find a book as soon as possible, Angular is so amazing!